# Datatables.net and sweetalert

Tags: datatables, sweetalert

So I am using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) and every row has a delete button at the end, which I use in combination with [Sweetalert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/).

I have 10 results per page and if for example there are more pages, and I go to the next page and try to use the delete button, nothing happens. It's like the sweetalert is not being rendered for anything else than the first 10 rows.

Below is my Sweetalert code, although I do not think it is related to this code since it works fine for the first 10 rows.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.deleteItem').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).parents('form');
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Some title',
                text: "Some text",
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {    
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am just wondering if anyone else using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) has ran into a similar issue or if someone knows what the issue might be. It's like only the first 10 rows are being rendered on the page.

The way I am initializing the datatable is simply as follows, so nothing fancy:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datatable').dataTable();
});
```

All my delete buttons look like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="something">
    <a type="submit" class="deleteItem">
        Delete
    </a>
</form>
```

Comment: The delete anchor on other pages aren't in the DOM when you attach the click handler. Listen for the `page` or `draw` events fired by datatables and assign the click handlers again. https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the other delete anchors are not in the DOM for the other pages. You can listen for the [`draw`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) event fired by DataTables and assign the click handler using Sweetalert there. I've defined a function `registerDeleteItemHandlers` to encapsulate the registration of the click event handlers.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  const registerDeleteItemHandlers = () => {
    $(".deleteItem").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this).parents("form");
      Swal.fire({
        title: "Some title",
        text: "Some text",
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
          form.submit();
        }
      });
    });
  };

  registerDeleteItemHandlers();

  $(".datatable")
    .dataTable()
    .on("draw.dt", function () {
      registerDeleteItemHandlers();
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool, learned something new, which was the main purpose, but yes this works, but only for all other pages but the first initialized one for some reason. So this solution reversed it ^^

Comment: I've edited the answer to use a function for registering the click event handlers so that it can be called at any point in the datatable lifecycle. Hopefully this works better for you.

Comment: Yes amazing, thank you for the lesson and of course the solution, will give the bounty when it allows me